# Extension to export addresses from TYPO3 tt_address to .csv file

Tags: typo3-11.x

Is there an extension that could be used to export emails and postal addresses from tt_address to a .csv file?
I tried the extension `maa_tt_address_export`but i think it's not compatible with TYPO3 Version 11 or 12 and i get the following error when trying to install it via composer:

`[InvalidArgumentException] Could not find a matching version of package maa_tt_address_export. Check the package spelling, your version constr aint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an additional extension as it is build in in the core.

In the TYPO3 BackEnd you can export records as CSV.
Go to List module and select the table you want to export (click on the table name).
In the head of the table you have an icon `Download` which opens a diologue where you can select `Columns to download`, `raw` or `processed values`, `filename` for export, format (`CSV` or `JSon`), `delimiter` and `quote character` for `CSV` or what kind of `meta information` for `JSon`.